# What is the proper way to do an operating system check in WiX bundle install

Tags: wix, installation, bundle, conditional-statements

In our WiX bundle install, we have an install condition (inside of a bal:Condition element).  It checks for various versions of the Windows O/S.  Is there a problem using a *greater than or equal* to in the following conditional?  Should this just be a simple equality instead (to avoid conflicting conditions)?

I'm asking because we had a condition failure on a Windows 7 install which indicated an incorrect service pack level (and we don't require any service pack for Windows 7 as you can tell from the rule below):

```
<bal:Condition Message="Cannot be installed">
    <!-- Windows XP SP3, Windows XP x64 SP2, Vista SP2, Windows 7 and higher -->
    <![CDATA[Installed OR ((VersionNT >= v5.1) AND (ServicePackLevel >= 3)) OR ((VersionNT >= v5.1) AND (ServicePackLevel >= 2) AND (VersionNT64)) OR ((VersionNT >= v6.0) AND (ServicePackLevel >= 2)) OR (VersionNT >= v6.1)]]>
</bal:Condition>
```

Note that version 6.0 is Windows Vista and 6.1 is Windows 7.